# Button for android layout

Tags: android, xml, button

I have used the below xml in drawable location

**button_square_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
    android:endColor="#80FF00FF" />
<padding
    android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<solid
    android:color="#848482" />
</shape>
```

I am using above xml & trying to change the button below

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/CopperChimneyFriendsButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_square_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

***I am trying to make the button to display as below in the figure. The button to have like a border ..... how can i change the code in button_square_shape.xml to achieve my goal ::***

Thanks,

[image: fig]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`<stroke>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#stroke-element) element? Also, there's no point using both `<gradient>` and `<solid>` - pick which one you want to fill the shape and use just that.